# Fitration based on bag of words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, multi-index

I have several mapping rules, here's the rules

```
Type A: Chicken, Beef, Goat
Type B: Fish, Shrimp
Type C: Chicken, Pork
```

I want to add this

```
 id   Menu
   1    Fried Chicken
   2    Shrimp Chips
   3    Pork with Cheese
   4    Fish Spaghetti
   5    Goat Sate
   6    Beef Soup
```

What I want to make labeling like this

```
 id     Menu                 Type A   Type B   Type C
   1    Fried Chicken        1        0        1
   2    Shrimp Chips         0        1        0
   3    Pork with Cheese     0        0        1
   4    Fish Spaghetti       0        1        0
   5    Goat Sate            1        0        0
   6    Beef Soup            1        0        0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I convert your mapping rules into a `pd.MultiIndex`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

m = {
    'Type A': ['Chicken', 'Beef', 'Goat'],
    'Type B': ['Fish', 'Shrimp'],
    'Type C': ['Chicken', 'Pork']
}

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(k, v) for k, values in m.items() for v in values])
```

---

**Option 0**
Simplest way using `pd.Series.str.get_dummies`

```
df.join(
    df.Menu.str.get_dummies(sep=' ') \
      .reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1, level=0)
)

   id              Menu  Type A  Type B  Type C
0   1     Fried Chicken       1       0       1
1   2      Shrimp Chips       0       1       0
2   3  Pork with Cheese       0       0       1
3   4    Fish Spaghetti       0       1       0
4   5         Goat Sate       1       0       0
5   6         Beef Soup       1       0       0
```

---

**Option 1**
Use `numpy.core.defchararray.find`

```
menu = df.Menu.values.astype(str)

d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    (find(menu[:, None], mux.levels[1]) >= 0).astype(int),
    columns = mux.levels[1]
)

df.join(d1.reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1, level=0))

   id              Menu  Type A  Type B  Type C
0   1     Fried Chicken       1       0       1
1   2      Shrimp Chips       0       1       0
2   3  Pork with Cheese       0       0       1
3   4    Fish Spaghetti       0       1       0
4   5         Goat Sate       1       0       0
5   6         Beef Soup       1       0       0
```

---

**Option 2**
Use `pd.Series.str.extractall`

```
d1 = pd.get_dummies(
    df.Menu.str.extractall(
        '({})'.format('|'.join(mux.levels[1]))
    )[0]
).sum(level=0)

df.join(d1.reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1, level=0))

   id              Menu  Type A  Type B  Type C
0   1     Fried Chicken       1       0       1
1   2      Shrimp Chips       0       1       0
2   3  Pork with Cheese       0       0       1
3   4    Fish Spaghetti       0       1       0
4   5         Goat Sate       1       0       0
5   6         Beef Soup       1       0       0
```

---

**Explanation of Option 1**
Using a `pd.MultiIndex` will enable me to use `np.core.defchararray.find` over only unique values of all the words I'm looking for and be able to map them back to the possible multiple keys.

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [(k, v) for k, values in m.items() for v in values])
```

`mux` will look like this:

```
 Type A           Type B         Type C     
Chicken Beef Goat   Fish Shrimp Chicken Pork
```

However, unique values of `mux` are in `mux.levels[1]`.  I use this to find my values using find.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(
    (find(menu[:, None], mux.levels[1]) >= 0).astype(int),
    columns = mux.levels[1]
)

d1

   Beef  Chicken  Fish  Goat  Pork  Shrimp
0     0        1     0     0     0       0
1     0        0     0     0     0       1
2     0        0     0     0     1       0
3     0        0     1     0     0       0
4     0        0     0     1     0       0
5     1        0     0     0     0       0
```

Now I can `pd.DataFrame.reindex` on `columns` and `level=1`

```
d1.reindex(columns=mux, level=1)

   Type A           Type B         Type C     
  Chicken Beef Goat   Fish Shrimp Chicken Pork
0       1    0    0      0      0       1    0
1       0    0    0      0      1       0    0
2       0    0    0      0      0       0    1
3       0    0    0      1      0       0    0
4       0    0    1      0      0       0    0
5       0    1    0      0      0       0    0
```

I take the `max` on `axis=1` and `level=0` and `join` that back... that's what I show above.

---

**Timing**

[image]

```
def pir0(df, m):
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [(k, v) for k, values in m.items() for v in values])

    return df.join(
        df.Menu.str.get_dummies(sep=' ') \
          .reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1, level=0)
    )

def pir1(df, m):
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [(k, v) for k, values in m.items() for v in values])

    menu = df.Menu.values.astype(str)

    d1 = pd.DataFrame(
        (find(menu[:, None], mux.levels[1]) >= 0).astype(int),
        columns = mux.levels[1]
    )

    return df.join(d1.reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1, level=0))

def pir2(df, m):
    mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [(k, v) for k, values in m.items() for v in values])

    d1 = pd.get_dummies(
        df.Menu.str.extractall(
            '({})'.format('|'.join(mux.levels[1]))
        )[0]
    ).sum(level=0)

    return df.join(d1.reindex(columns=mux, level=1).max(axis=1, level=0))


def keiku(df, m):
    return df.assign(**{k: df.Menu.str.contains('|'.join(m[k])).astype(int) for k in m})


res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000],
    columns='pir0 pir1 pir2 keiku'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d, m)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, m, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=20)

res.plot(loglog=True)
```

Comment: Can you add timings?

Comment: Thank you for timings, I notice now you add it.

Answer (score 3):

There is the following code as a simple solution.

```python
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

m = {
    'Type A': ['Chicken', 'Beef', 'Goat'],
    'Type B': ['Fish', 'Shrimp'],
    'Type C': ['Chicken', 'Pork']
}

csv = StringIO("""id,Menu
1,Fried Chicken
2,Shrimp Chips
3,Pork with Cheese
4,Fish Spaghetti
5,Goat Sate
6,Beef Soup""")
df = pd.read_csv(csv)

for key in m:
    df[key] = df["Menu"].str.contains('|'.join(m[key])).astype(int)

df
# Out[3]: 
#    id              Menu  Type A  Type B  Type C
# 0   1     Fried Chicken       1       0       1
# 1   2      Shrimp Chips       0       1       0
# 2   3  Pork with Cheese       0       0       1
# 3   4    Fish Spaghetti       0       1       0
# 4   5         Goat Sate       1       0       0
# 5   6         Beef Soup       1       0       0
```

Comment: As cool as I think my answer is.  This is simpler and faster.  However, I'd change it to this `df.assign(**{k: df.Menu.str.contains('|'.join(m[k])).astype(int) for k in m})`

Comment: Thank you for your supplement and time measurement. Your answer has also been studied.

Comment: One thing I haven't tested is what happens as there are more keys to the dictionary.  I'll play with that later.  Anyway, good answer!